# python3 aiogram. How to send message to user_id

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

```
from aiogram import Bot
import config

def send_message(message):
    operator = Bot(config.operator_token)
    operator.send_message(config.user_id, message)

def main():
    send_message('hi')
```

I want to send message to user with id from my config.py (config.user_id). But it's not workinkg. I tried many ways for it but I always got an error.

For example like this

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f94a9b62550>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7f94a98f8040>, 
23065.38)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7f94a9b3c400>'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use aiogram you must use async/await to send message.

```
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot_init)
    
@dp.message_handler(commands=['test'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "test message") #like this
    #await message.answer("test message") 
    #or like this
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?!

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot
import config

async def send_message(message):
    operator = Bot(config.operator_token)
    await operator.send_message(config.user_id, message)


def main():
    asyncio.run(send_message('hi'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

from config import TOKEN


bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hello\nWrite me something!")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def process_help_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Implementation EchoBot")


@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```